# Intersection of subspaces, show $W=\operatorname{span}S$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space, and let $S \subset V$ be any subset. Define $W$ to be the intersection of all the subspaces $Z$ of $V$ that satisfy $S \subset Z \subset V$.

a) Show that $W$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ that contains $S$. This means: show that $W$ is a subspace, show that $S \subset W$ and show that if $Y \subset V$ satisfies (i) $Y$ is a subspace and (ii) $S \subset Y$, then we must have $W \subset Y$.

b) Use part (a) to show that $W=\operatorname{span} S$

Comment: Where are you stuck? You should be able to walk through the points as listed in the task

Comment: Managed to show that W is a subspace (because the intersection of any arbitrary collection of subspaces is a subspace) so I am stuck at $S \subset W$.

Comment: Let $x \in S$, since $S \subset Z$ then $x \in Z$. But $W$ is the intersection of all subspaces $Z$. Then $Z$ contains $W$. Therefore: $\forall x \in S, x \in Z$ which implies $\forall x \in S, x \in W$. $S \subset W$. Is this a correct approach?

Comment: Writing \operatorname{span}S instead of \textrm{span}\,S automatically results in proper spacing including space to the left and right of "span" in things like $A\operatorname{span}B$ and a smaller space to the right in things like $A\operatorname{span}(B)$.  I changed it. $\qquad$

Comment: This question is phrased in language suitable for assigning homework.  That is frowned on here, since it can lead to reasonable suspicions that you simply copied a question without even understanding the question.  Can you explain at what point you had difficulty with this?  If you don't understand the question itself, you can ask about that. $\qquad$

Comment: I explained 2 comments above.